# Add user to group at a later point in puppet

Tags: puppet

I have a user resource in a module that gets used by several different nodes. Now I want to add this user to a group but only in one specific node. Is there a good solution for this?

Module looks something like this:

```
class testmodule::basics {
  user { 'testuser':
    ensure     => present,
    home       => '/home/testuser',
    managehome => true,
  }
}
```

Node manifest:

```
node 'testnode' {
  include testmodule::basics

  # here I would like to add the user to a group
  # something like this (obviously does not work because of duplicate resource)

  user { 'testuser':
    groups     => 'testgroup',
    membership => 'minimum',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several alternatives, split among several general categories.

***Category 1*** - use external data to communicate which secondary groups the user should have.  The particular datum might be a flag to indicate whether the user should be in the secondary group, or it might be an actual array of the appropriate secondary groups.  You might then obtain it either by directly calling the `lookup()` or `hiera()` function, depending on which version of Puppet you are using, or by creating a class parameter for it, and using automatic data binding.

Example:

**modules/testmodule/manifests/basics.pp**:

```
class testmodule::basics($secondary_groups = []) {
  user { 'testuser':
    ensure     => present,
    home       => '/home/testuser',
    managehome => true,
    groups     => $secondary_groups
  }
}
```

**data/nodes/special.my.com.yaml**:

```
---
testmodule::basics::secondary_groups:
  - testgroup
```

***Category 2*** - Set up a class parameter to receive the distinguishing data, just as in one of the category 1 options, and feed the data in via an external node classifier (ENC), instead of external data.  Setting up and enabling an ENC has much broader implications than feeding data to a single class, however, so I don't really recommend this unless you are already using or planning to use an ENC.

***Category 3*** - Perform a resource parameter override where needed.  This could be almost a drop-in change to your example manifest, though it would be better to put the override in a separate class than to perform it directly in the node block.  In a class that `inherits` from `testmodule::basics`, you can use resource parameter override syntax, like so:

**modules/testmodule/manifests/basics/special.pp**:

```
class testmodule::basics::special inherits testmodule::basics {
  User['testuser'] {
    groups     => 'testgroup'
  }
}
```

If you want to perform such an override in a node block or in an unrelated class, however, then you need to do it via a collector:

```
node 'testnode' {
  include testmodule::basics

  User<title == 'testuser'> {
    groups     => 'testgroup'
  }
}
```

To two varieties of overrides have some subtle differences beyond the scopes in which they may be used, so do read [the docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.4/lang_resources_advanced.html#adding-or-modifying-attributes) for more information.

Comment: Here is what worked for me: `User<|title == "ubuntu"|> { groups => ["ubuntu", "docker"] }`.